# Can higher dimensional spheres be regularly partitioned/discretized?

Tags: geometry, spheres, platonic-solids

A circle can be partitioned into $n\in\mathbb{N}$ congruent 1-spherical line segments similar to the regular polygons.

A sphere can be partitioned into $n\in\{4,6,20\}$ congruent 2-spherical equilateral triangles similar to the tetra-, octa-, and icosahedron.

Is that the end of the story, or is it possible to partition a glome into congruent 3-spherical tetrahedrons for some $n$s?

Answer (score 3):

The question is equivalent to asking for [regular polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope) whose facets are [simplices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex). There are two infinite families: the simplices themselves (which are generalizations of tetrahedra), and the [cross-polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope) (which are generalizations of octahedra). [In four dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_4-polytope#Regular_convex_4-polytopes), there is also the [600-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/600-cell).